# Magento Payment via Deposit

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

I'd like to make available in checkout the opportunity for the customer to pay 25% of the total of the transaction. The rest of the payment would be taken offline (outside of Magento).

Can anyone advise on firstly, if this is possible, and secondly if there's anything I can add to the checkout.phtml to achieve this?

Comment: You can 75% discount rule so that customer only have to pay 25%. But this will effect the overall order amount if it's a concern